# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.basicprofileapp.dataholder.setUsername(java.lang.String)'on a null object refrence

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception

I was creating a basic application that takes input and stores it in a firebase database with auto incrementing but it crashes everytime giving a nullpointer exception.

I think there is some problem in my dataholder java file but I can't fix it.

I've tried changing arguments in dataholder file.i have checked my android manifest file for firebase services.

Here's my dataholder java file

```
public class dataholder {

    String username,password1;

    public dataholder(String username, String password1) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password1 = password1;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword1() {
        return password1;
    }

    public void setPassword1(String password1) {
        this.password1 = password1;
    }
}
```

and MainActivity

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    EditText password;
    Button login;


    DatabaseReference reff;
    dataholder obj;

    long maxid = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);

        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dataholder");
        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                    maxid = (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                obj.setUsername(name.getText().toString().trim());
                obj.setPassword1(password.getText().toString().trim());

                reff.child(String.valueOf(maxid + 1)).setValue("obj");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data inserted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field `dataholder obj` is never set, so it be null when you to access it in the `OnClickListener` for the `Button` called "login".

You'll need to assign `obj` to an actual value before you can access the getters/setters, such as `obj = new dataholder(...)`.

Comment: Happy to hear that @tanujabhatnagar! Don't forget to mark this as the answer. 